# Blazor Wasm Making API Requests

Tags: api, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Just a general question.  I have a blazor wasm hosted server app which is going to poll data from a free api (mlbstats api).  Frequent polling will occur to get the status of players, stats, etc during a game.  Should I have the client poll the mlb stats api or the server?  I feel like if I had the server do it and there were a lot of users at one time then that could overwhelm their API and I would be blocked. I guess the alternative would be to have the server poll all the data every 15 seconds or so and then push out through a signalR hub for the clients to handle.

I have it working in development but feel like a may run into some problems with production either way.

Comment: `I guess the alternative would be to have the server poll all the data every 15 seconds or so and then push out through a signalR hub for the clients to handle.` -- That would be my preferred approach.

Comment: Wouldn't that be too much data though?  I worry it could slow down the server say if 16 games are going on at one time.

Comment: I would imagine that you only have to push changes to individual clients.